# How to set the cell width in itextsharp pdf creation

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

How can I set cell width and height in itextsharp pdf cell ceration using c#. I just use

```
cell.width = 200f;
```

But it should display the error message.

> width can not be set.

What should I do?..

Answer (score 14, accepted):

http://indaravind.blogspot.in/2009/02/itextsharp-table-column-width.html

VB:

```
Dim intTblWidth() As Integer = {12, 10, 26, 10}
```

C#:

```
int[] intTblWidth = { 12, 10, 26, 10 };
```

Comment: Lol, that is VB and the question is C#

Comment: logic is same..he has to define cell width basically

Answer (score 39):

You don't set the width of a cell.

you should set the width of the columns. And you can do that by applying them on the table object:

```
float[] widths = new float[] { 1f, 2f };
table.SetWidths(widths);
```

The answer from Neha is to set the width of the table object

more reference material here: http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables

Answer (score 1):

```
int  count=Gridview1.Columns.Count
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(count);
float[] columnWidths = new float[count];
for (int v = 0; v < count; v++)
{
    if (v == 0) { 
    columnWidths[v] = 10f;
    }
    else if (v == 2)
    {
        columnWidths[v] = 30f;
    }
    else if(v == 3)
    {
        columnWidths[v] = 15f;
    }
    else if(v == 4)
    {
        columnWidths[v] = 18f;
    }
    else if(v == 5|| v == 6|| v == 7)
    {
        columnWidths[v] = 22f;
    }
    else
    {
        columnWidths[v] = 20f;
    }
}

table.SetWidths(columnWidths);
```

Comment: Whilst this may or may not be the answer it would be beneficial to explain what you are doing here, for example what are all of these abitrary numbers that you're plucking out of nowhere. Is there a resource you used for this? Maybe you can link to it to be a little more helpful?

Comment: I set column width in itextsharp pdf cell ceration using c#. I just use the above code it is helpful for dynamic columns

Answer (score 0):

```
#region Name..!!

            PdfPTable tblName = new PdfPTable(3);
            tblName.WidthPercentage = 98f;
            float[] colWidthsaccing4 = { 100, 500, 700 };
            tblName.SetWidths(colWidthsaccing4);
            PdfPCell celladdingo4;
            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0;
            celladdingo4.Colspan = 2;
            tblHeader6.AddCell(celladdingo4);

            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("1.", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            
            celladdingo4.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblName.AddCell(celladdingo4);

            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  Name :", TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            celladdingo4.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblName.AddCell(celladdingo4);

            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" " +dt.Rows[0]["EmpName"].ToString(), TableFontmini_ARBold8Nor));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
            celladdingo4.PaddingBottom = 5f;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0.5f;
            tblName.AddCell(celladdingo4);

            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0;
            celladdingo4.Colspan = 2;
            tblHeader6.AddCell(celladdingo4);

            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0;
            celladdingo4.Colspan = 2;
            tblHeader6.AddCell(celladdingo4);

            celladdingo4 = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("  ", Smallspace));
            celladdingo4.HorizontalAlignment = 1;
            celladdingo4.BorderWidth = 0;
            celladdingo4.Colspan = 2;
            
            tblHeader6.AddCell(celladdingo4);


            doc.Add(tblName);

            #endregion
```

Comment: Is all this code necessary to set width and height of a single cell?

Answer (score -3):

`cell.width = 200f;` you have to put capital W on width correct is `cell.Width = 200f;`

Comment: Setting width on a cell is not allowed

Comment: There is not the option to set width on cell.