# Downloaded PDF Width Issue

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, itext

I'm using the piece of code that appears below to export my web page to pdf using the library iTextSharp. The web page is divided into two columns, having one column with 90% width and the other column width is 10%. But, when downloaded as PDF, both the columns allocate the same width. Each column takes 50% width in the downloaded PDF.

```
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=ResumeTemplate.pdf");
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
wrapper.RenderControl(hw);

Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 100f, 0f);

PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, Response.OutputStream);
pdfDoc.Open();
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sw.ToString());

HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);

htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
Response.Write(pdfDoc);
Response.End();
```

Below is my HTML Code:

```
<table border="0" width="100%" id="maintable" runat="server" >
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="content_left" runat="server"  style="margin-right:10px; float:left;vertical-align:top;width:90%" >
                </td>
                <td>
                    <div id="content_right" runat="server" style="vertical-align:top;width:10%">
                    </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

The div `content_left` and `content_right` displays exactly with specified width in the page. When it is downloaded as Word, it displays with exact css in the WebPage. But, when downloaded as PDF, `content_left` and `content_right` take equal width respective to the page size (50% width allocated to both `content_left` and `content_right`).

Comment: Your HTML snippet is invalid, I've formatted it so that you can see that the 1st `<div>` is not properly closed. Was it on purpose? Could that be the cause of your issue?

Comment: No,its not the cause of issue,even if the div is formatted correctly,the downloaded pdf will have same width  for both content_left and content_right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code the div's are 90% and 10% of their parent element size (td). Since tables are original designed to display table's and not define layout, the cell sizes balance out. The td's are not 50% - 50% or 90% - 10%. But adjust size based on the content.

In the snippet below I defined the size on the td. See the fiddle for before and afther: http://jsfiddle.net/allcaps/tEGB8/1/

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td width="90%">
            <div id="content_left" style="background-color:red;">Foo</div>
        </td>
        <td width="10%">
            <div id="content_right" style="background-color:blue;">Foo</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

### Update

iTextSharp ignores width attributes on table columns/cells. You have to set the sizes like suggested in this thread: 
[How to set the cell width in itextsharp pdf creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208482/how-to-set-the-cell-width-in-itextsharp-pdf-creation)

```
Dim intTblWidth() As Integer = {12, 10, 26, 10}
```

Comment: Yes.you are correct ,the above table will display like the one in the below fiddle.http://jsfiddle.net/allcaps/tEGB8/1/  But,when the same content is downloaded as pdf(code given in my older post),the td inside table will share equal width

Comment: Just to be clear: Did you try to convert the fiddle code to pdf? I don't develop .Net/iTextSharp so can't test it. I know your html doesn't render to pdf the way you want. That is why I supplied you the new html.

Comment: yes.I converted the fiddle code and downloaded the same as pdf and the issue remains

Comment: I find it strange that a html2pdf tool (iTextSharp) does't honor the html. Did you try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208482/how-to-set-the-cell-width-in-itextsharp-pdf-creation

Comment: Thank You.That Link solved my width issue.But,when i tried to render my user control to pdfpcell ,I'm facing the issue.Because in my page all the controls is dynamically created and finally adding it to a div and now I want that div to be added in PdfpCell, which I'm not able to do.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the comments. You are right: The fix would be to scrape the html, look for attributes on your div and use those to generate the right iTextShap instructions for the table. If that doesn't work, than look for an alternative to iTextSharp.