# I want to increase the width of the first column in itextsharp pdf creation

Tags: c#, pdf, datagridview, itext

I want to increase the width of the first column matricule in itextsharp pdf creation
The picture shows what I want
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7byGj.png)

```
PdfPTable pdfTable = new PdfPTable(dataGridView4.ColumnCount);
        //pdfTable. = 5;

        pdfTable.DefaultCell.Padding = 3;
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
        pdfTable.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;


        pdfTable.WidthPercentage = 100;
       // pdfTable.SetWidths(GetHeaderWidths(font.GetFont("ARIAL", 30), headers));

        pdfTable.DefaultCell.VerticalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;
        //pdfTa = Element.ALIGN_MIDDLE;
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.BorderWidth = 1;
        //pdfTable.DefaultCell.Width = 10;(
        //pdfTable.TotalWidth = 300;
        pdfTable.DefaultCell.UseAscender = true;
        iTextSharp.text.Font fon = FontFactory.GetFont("ARIAL", 30);
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView4.Columns)
        {

            int c = 0;


            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(column.HeaderText));
            if (c == 0)
            {
                // pdfTable.SetWidths(c);

               // column.HeaderText = "330";
               // dataGridView4.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.AllCells;
                // pdfTable.AddCell(cell);
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can custom the width using `pdfptable`

```
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(5); // this will be your # of columns.
table.HorizontalAlignment = 0;
table.TotalWidth = 500f;
table.LockedWidth = true;
float[] widths = new float[] { 20f, 60f, 60f, 30f, 50f };
table.SetWidths(widths);
```

this is what you want to concentrate on:

```
 float[] widths = new float[] { 20f, 60f, 60f, 30f, 50f };
```

here is the article which may help you:
[Source](https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/86/iTextSharp-Introducing-Tables)

**another complete example:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Document doc = new Document();
    try {
        PdfWriter.getInstance(doc, new FileOutputStream("TableColumnWidth.pdf"));
        doc.open();

        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(4);
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 1")));
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 2")));
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 3")));
        table.addCell(new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Cell 4")));

        // Defiles the relative width of the columns
        float[] columnWidths = new float[]{10f, 20f, 30f, 10f};
        table.setWidths(columnWidths);

        doc.add(table);
    } catch (DocumentException | FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        doc.close();
    }
}
```

[source](https://kodejava.org/how-do-i-set-column-width-of-a-table-in-itext/)

Comment: Hello
thank you for your reply
The code didn't work. Is there another way,

Comment: The problem has been resolved Thank you .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9208482/how-to-set-the-cell-width-in-itextsharp-pdf-creation

Comment: Good to hear! Cheers.